# How much of a tank can I destroy without losing the liquid?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-railcraft

I can knock a block out of a railcraft tank, replace it, and the liquid inside will be magically restored. However I just expanded my 5x5 tank to a 7x7 tank by knocking out a corner of it and the liquid did not come back.

Under what conditions will the liquid inside a tank be kept? When will they not?

Note that my experience seems to contradict the notice on the wiki:

> If you have an accident with your tank and all your liquid appears to disappear don't worry as long as the bottom center block is still intact, replace the broken block and your liquid should reappear.

Comment: The notice on the wiki may only apply to repairing the tank as it was previously configured and not to expanding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General rule for Railcraft mutli-block structures is that as long as the bottom middle block is left alone then the meta data (contents of a tank in this case) will be fine.

Now there is a bit of stickiness to this. We have completely destroyed coke ovens for example (with the express purpose of remove the oil we did not want) and replaced the blocks again and the information was still there. So it seems as long as the same block is placed in the same location again the information sticks around.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Disagree. I'm thinking maybe the whole frame of the tank needs to be intact (allowing for extension upwards only), but I'm not in a position to test now.

Comment: Nope, its only the bottom center man.. I have broken things down and replaced items from valves all the way to the entire tank save one block when doing a very aggressive rework of a room with some tanks in it. Happy testing though :)

Comment: ...so when you expand a tank, the bottom center changes (if you don't expand directly outwards on all sides.)

Comment: You will loose what the tank had in it if you expand it and do not keep the center of the tank in place. Depending on how much liquid you want to move and what other mods  you have available to you you may want to store it in a separate tank or chest (use capsules if possible as they stack).

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Railcraft wiki:

> If you have an accident with your tank and all your liquid appears to disappear don't worry as long as the bottom center block is still intact, replace the broken block and your liquid should reappear.

http://railcraft.info/wiki/device:iron_tank